# Some basic seq and list questions

Tags: f#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linked list partition function and reversed results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199122/linked-list-partition-function-and-reversed-results)

Actually I don't care about the input type or the output type, any of `seq, array, list` will do. (It doesn't have to be generic)  Currently my code takes `list` as input and `(list * list)` as output

```
let takeWhile predicator list =
   let rec takeWhileRec newList remain =
       match remain with
       | [] -> (newList |> List.rev, remain)
       | x::xs -> if predicator x then
                     takeWhileRec (x::newList) xs
                  else
                     (newList |> List.rev, remain)
   takeWhileRec [] list
```

However, there is a pitfall. As fas as I see, `List.rev` is O(n^2), which would likely to dominate the overall speed? I think it is even slower than the ugly solution: `Seq.takeWhile`, then `count`, and then take `tail` n times... which is still O(n)

(If there is a C# List, then i would use that without having to reverse it...)

A side question, what's difference between `Array.ofList` and `List.toArray` , or more generally, `A.ofB` and `B.ofA` in `List, Seq, Array`?

is `seq myList` identical to `List.toSeq myList`?

Another side question, is nested `Seq.append` have same complexity as `Seq.concat`?

e.g.

```
  Seq.append (Seq.append (Seq.append a b) c) d // looks aweful
  Seq.concat [a;b;c;d]
```

Comment: If `List.rev` really bugs you, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7199989/162396) to a similar question for a continuation-based version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)The relevant implementation of `List.rev` is in `local.fs` in the compiler - it is

```
// optimized mutation-based implementation. This code is only valid in fslib, where mutation of private
// tail cons cells is permitted in carefully written library code.
let rec revAcc xs acc =
    match xs with
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t -> revAcc t (h::acc)

let rev xs =
    match xs with
    | [] -> xs
    | [_] -> xs
    | h1::h2::t -> revAcc t [h2;h1]
```

The comment does seem odd as there is no obvious mutation.  Note that this is in fact `O(n)` not `O(n^2)`

2) As pad said there is no difference - I prefer to use the `to..` as I think

```
A
|> List.map ...
|> List.toArray
```

looks nicer than

```
A
|> List.map ...
|> Array.ofList
```

but that is just me.

3)

Append (compiler source):

```
[<CompiledName("Append")>]
let append (source1: seq<'T>) (source2: seq<'T>) =
    checkNonNull "source1" source1
    checkNonNull "source2" source2
    fromGenerator(fun () -> Generator.bindG (toGenerator source1) (fun () -> toGenerator source2))
```

Note that for each append we get an extra generator that has to be walked through.  In comparison, the concat implementation will just have 1 single extra function rather than `n` so using `concat` is probably better.

Comment: is `seq myList` identical to `List.toSeq myList`?

Comment: @colinfang -  It appears that way but I am not sure

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1) Time complexity of [List.rev](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/local.fs#L117) is `O(n)` and worst-case complexity of `takeWhile` is also `O(n)`. So using `List.rev` doesn't increase complexity of the function. Using `ResizeArray` could help you avoid `List.rev`, but you have to tolerate a bit of mutation.

```
let takeWhile predicate list =
   let rec loop (acc: ResizeArray<_>) rest =
       match rest with       
       | x::xs when predicate x -> acc.Add(x); loop acc xs
       | _ -> (acc |> Seq.toList, rest)
   loop (ResizeArray()) list
```

2) There is no difference. `Array.ofList` and `List.toArray` uses the same function internally (see [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/array.fs#L140) and [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/list.fs#L49)).

3). I think `Seq.concat` has the same complexity with a bunch of `Seq.append`. In the context of `List` and`Array`,  `concat` is more efficient than `append` because you have more information to pre-allocate space for outputs.

Comment: is `seq myList` identical to `List.toSeq myList`?

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
let takeWhile pred =
    let cont = ref true
    List.partition (pred >> fun r -> !cont && (cont := r; r))
```

It uses a single library function, List.partition, which is efficiently implemented.
Hope this is what you meant :)

Comment: I doubt it is *efficient* because you always have to traverse the whole list and the overhead of `ref` cell.

Comment: Just a word of caution -- in functional programming, the variable name `cont` is often used for a *continuation*, and it can be a bit confusing when it's used for some other variable. You might want to choose a different variable name next time (e.g., `finished` or `done`).